# HTML/JS music playlist script

Tags: javascript, html, audio-player

I'm pretty new to JS, and I've been asked to create a music player that can run out of a single HTML file. the music is hosted on a google drive because it has to be able to be changed for holidays/season etc

after a lot of cobbling code together and testing and troubleshooting, I've managed to get the playlist to run and loop pretty consistently, but I'm running into an issue where the playlist freezes on a song randomly. it's usually after it's looped at least once, and the only explanation I can gather is that the connection drops or for some reason the script can't connect to the music file.

Is there a way to detect if the song failed to play, skip over it by incrementing localstorage.songposition by one and playing the next one? You can see I was trying this with try and catch blocks, but I guess it doesn't generate an error in JS, because this doesn't work.

in the code below, I removed the links to our files, but it should play the first link just fine, the second link is left intentionally broken, and it should detect that it cant play #2 and skip to the third.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HTML5 Audio Player</title>
    <style>
        body { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); }
        #playlist{
            list-style: none;
        }
        #playlist li a{
            color:#322f31;
            text-decoration: none;
            -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #232022;
            font-size: 28px;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
        #playlist .current-song a{
            color:#ee273c;
            font-weight:bold;
            -webkit-text-stroke: 1.5px #9a1723;
            font-size: 32px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- -->
    <!--Audio Player--> 
    <audio src="" controls id="audioPlayer" hidden> <!---->
        Sorry, your browser doesn't support html5!
    </audio>
    <!-- List of songs -->
    <ul id="playlist"> 
        <!--Set 1, Song 1 --><li class="current-song"><a href="Link_here">It Goes Like This</a></li>
        <!--Set 2, Song 1 --><li><a href="Broken LInk">Testing Link</a></li>
        <!--Set 3, Song 1 --><li><a href="Link_here">Destination Unknown</a></li>

    </ul>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">

        function audioPlayer(){
            var currentSong = 0;
            try{
                //If the locally stored position doesn't exist yet, set it to currentSong, otherwise increment it by one
                if (localStorage.songPosition === "NaN"){
                    localStorage.songPosition = currentSong
                }
                else{
                    localStorage.songPosition++
                }
                //If the stored song position is greater than the length of the song index, reset it.
                if(localStorage.songPosition > $("#playlist li a").length-1){
                        localStorage.songPosition = 0;
                        currentSong = 0;
                }
                //Play the song at the locally stored position
                $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[localStorage.songPosition];
                $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
                //Removes the class from the last song and adds the current-song class to the playing song to color it blue
                $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
                $("#playlist li:eq("+localStorage.songPosition+")").addClass("current-song");
                //Allows you to click titles to change songs, this is mostly for an actual web page and not necessary for an automatic system.
                $("#playlist li a").click(function(e){
                   e.preventDefault(); 
                   //Play next song
                   $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = this;
                   $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
                   //Move current-song class to next song
                   $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
                    currentSong = $(localStorage.songPosition).parent().index();
                    $(this).parent().addClass("current-song");
                });
                //Check for the end of the current song, increment the current song counter and play the next one.
                $("#audioPlayer")[0].addEventListener("ended", function(){
                   currentSong++;
                   localStorage.songPosition = currentSong;
                    if(localStorage.songPosition > $("#playlist li a").length-1){
                        currentSong = 0;
                        localStorage.songPosition = 0;
                    }
                    //Move the current-song class to the next song
                    $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
                    $("#playlist li:eq("+currentSong+")").addClass("current-song");
                    //Play next song
                    $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[localStorage.songPosition].href;
                    $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();                
                });
            }
            catch(err) {
                alert("catch")
                localStorage.songPosition++
                $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[localStorage.songPosition];
                $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
            }
        }

    </script>
    <script>
        // loads the audio player
        audioPlayer();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using ready libraries, like https://github.com/MoePlayer/APlayer

Comment: The problem with that is that I can't modify anything on the hardware, this is just an HTML script that's running through another program. it's basically remotely managed powerpoint, and I can upload an HTML script to run, but I can't install any programs or a hierarchy of files.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in javascript just put < script > around it I don't think that it will pause on one song like yours did

```
document.onkeydown = keydown;

var paused = false;
function keydown(evt) {
  if (!evt) evt = event;
  if (evt.keyCode == 39) {
    // right arrow key
    evt.preventDefault();
    x.currentTime += 10;
  }
  if (evt.keyCode == 37) {
    //left arrow key
    evt.preventDefault();
    x.currentTime -= 10;
  }
  if (evt.keyCode == 119) {
    //enter
    evt.preventDefault();
    x.currentTime = x.duration;
  }
  if (evt.keyCode == 32) {
    //space
    evt.preventDefault();
    if(paused == false){
      x.pause();
      paused = true;
    }
    else{
      x.play();
      paused = false;
    }
  }
}
  var songList = [
   //links to songs
   //song1,
   //song2
];

          function randomChoice(choices) {
            var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
            return choices[index];
          }
          function error(){
             play()
          }
            function playAudio() {
            try{x.pause();}catch(err){
              //pass}finally{
              x = randomChoice(songList);
            x = new Audio(x);
            x.id = 'x';
            x.play();
            //autoplay
            x.addEventListener("ended", function playNextS() {playAudio()})
            }};
          function pauseAudio() {
              x.pause();
          }
```

then just put

or

but if you wanted to you could do something like

var current = 0; setInterval(function(){oldTime = current; current = x.currentTime; if(currentTime == oldTime && x.paused == false){play()}elif(x.nodeType != 1){play}, 10000)

to check every x seconds if the song is still playing